# Alamofire cancel a request out of multiple requests

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to upload a several files to my server with separate requests at once, the file names are displayed in a tableView along with a progress bar. When the user tries to delete a file while it's uploading the tableView cell should be removed and the request should be cancelled.

I know the following code is to be used to cancel an Alamofire request:

```
var request: Alamofire.Request?
self.request?.cancel()
```

So, I tried making an array of Alamofire.Request like

```
var requests = [Alamofire.Request]()
```

And then cancelling the request according to the index.

But this doesn't seem to be the correct way because it's not working, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) cancel would:

> Cancels the underlying task, producing an error that is passed to any registered response handlers.

Therefore, add a response handler to your request and see whether error messages are passed to them. If so, it means that the cancel operates correctly.

Comment: I think I was not clear in my question. I was able to implement cancel() successfully for a single request. What I need is, how to implement cancel() for multiple simultaneous requests?

Comment: Simply loop the array of requests and create a cancel handler from inside the loop.